# Use capacitive Back button to goBack(); in fragment activity in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-activity

i have build a new app and in that app i have 3 fragments with webview in it. basically i want to implement goBack(); on capacitive back button. i did tried

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    webView.goBack();
return;
}
```

and also

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        webView.goBack();
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but i end up with errors. so can anyone help me doing this. Thank you
and it is a

```
public class AdminM extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener
```

Comment: What kind of errors? Can you show them?

Comment: The method onBackPressed() of type AdminM.Fragment2 must override or implement a supertype method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get "The method onBackPressed() of type AdminM.Fragment2 must override or implement a supertype method" because you added Override annotation, but there is no onBackPressed method in Fragment. You can override onBackPressed only in an Activity.
You can look at the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) docs to see what methods you can override and what methods you can not override.

The right way would be to retrieve the Fragment from FragmentManager every time before accessing it. This way you can be sure you're using the right instance. If the Fragment is null, it's not attached.

In Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final WebViewFragment fragment = (WebViewFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(fragmentId);
    if (fragment == null || !fragment.onBackPressed()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In Fragment, create a method that returns true if WebView got back and false if not.
Check every time if webView is null, because fragmen has it's own lifecycle mechanism.

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is may be a foolish question but can u tell where should i put this activity part!

Comment: having 2 errors 1: fragmentManager cannot be resolved 2: The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type WebView

Comment: @user2966615 You will get errors because you have to modify the code. Create a fragmentManager field and replace fragmentId with your actual Fragment id. The fragment you are referencing should be called WebViewFragment or replace "WebViewFragment" with your actual Fragment name. And you will have to handle if the fragment is visible to use the back button properly since you have tabs, but that's a whole different story.